# How can I remove every nth character from a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string which contains a random character after every 5th character like:

```
let string = "You s$eem t%o be =very [happy? thes+e day$s!"
```

How can I remove the the unwanted characters after every 5 characters and get the correct string like this:

```
"You seem to be very happy these days!"
```

The characters to be removed may be any kind of characters like special characters, numbers and alphabets. The thing is they are inserted after every 5 characters in the string. So, the characters after every 5 characters need to be removed to get correct string.

I wrote this code to insert a character after every 5 characters but confused with removing it. So, please help me to do it.

````
var string = "You seem to be very happy these days!";
saltedString = string.split('').reduce((a, e, i)=> a + e + (i % 5 === 4 ? Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 1) : ''), '');
console.log(saltedString)```
````

Comment: What code have you attempted? You should add that to your question.

Comment: @Andy I added my attempt. Can you help me?

Comment: Those characters aren't spaced 5 characters apart btw.

Comment: `string.filter((c,i) => i % 5 !== 0);`

Comment: They are.. spaces are also counted as one character while inserting them.

Comment: No, they are 5 characters from _each other_, not every 5th character as you claim in your question.

Comment: @Andy The question says "after every 5th character" which I would interpret as every 6th character. I understand that one could interpret it differently, but with the example it should be clear anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regex similar to your example. It stores a group of 5 characters with `(.{5})` and matches an additional (6th) character with `.`. Then it replaces this with the group of 5 characters only, leaving out the 6th one.

```js
const string = "You s$eem t%o be =very [happy? thes+e day$s!"
const saltedString = string.replace(/(.{5})./g,"$1")
console.log(saltedString)
```

Comment: Had a similar problem but it was your explanation that made me know how to solve mine. Appreciate

Answer (score 2):

In one line:

```
const s = '1234567890'.split('').filter((c, i) => (i + 1) % 5 !== 0).join('');
console.log(s);
// 12346789
const s = 'You s$eem t%o be =very [happy? thes+e day$s!'.split('').filter((c, i) => (i + 1) % 6 !== 0).join('');
console.log(s);
// You seem to be very happy these days!
```

Note that those characters are 6 apart, not 5.

Answer (score 2):

You could split the string into an array, and then [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) out the 5th character making sure to decrement the variable that holds the length of the array by one.

```js
const str = "You s$eem t%o be =very [happy? thes+e day$s!";

function removeChar(str, n) {

  // Create an array from the string
  const arr = str.split('');

  // Iterate over the array
  // We make sure to create a separate variable for the
  // array length so that we can decrement when the
  // condition is met
  for (let i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {

    // We want to match the index of the character to `n`
    // We use modulo here to check the remainder,
    // but we don't want to eliminate the character at index 0
    if (i > 0 && i % 5 === 0) {

      // When the condition is met, splice out the element
      // and decrement the length value
      arr.splice(i, 1);
      l--;
    }
  }

  // Return a joined-up array
  return arr.join('');
}

console.log(removeChar(str, 5));
```

Answer (score 1):

Split and join the string with that condition.

```js
let string = "You s$eem t%o be =very [happy? thes+e day$s!";
let startIndex = 0;
let newStrArray = [];
while (startIndex < string.length) {
  newStrArray.push(string.substring(startIndex, startIndex + 5));
  startIndex += 6;
}
console.log(newStrArray.join(''));
```

Answer (score 1):

Created a `string.removeAt(index)`  method removes character at specified  index.  A little solution but very effective !

```
  let string = "You s$eem t%o be =very [happy? thes+e day$s!"

  String.prototype.removeAt = function (index) {
    let array = Array.from(this);
    delete array[index];
    let str = array.reduce((acc, char)=> acc += char, "")
    return str
  }

  // Function loops through string and remove character after every specified index 

  function  clear(string , index) {
    for (let i = index; i < string.length; i = i + index) {
      string = string.removeAt(i)
    }
    return string;
  }

  console.log(clear(string, 5))
```

Comment: @Bibek Oli  Does this answer solves your problem ?

Comment: @Bibek Oli You can use this `string.removeAt()` method on any string datatype cool huh ( removes character at specific index)  in any string datatype ! Cool huh